# Remove NaN in a python list using max

Tags: python, max

In a recent interview I was given the following problem.

We have a list `l = [NaN, 5, -12, NaN, 9, 0]` and we want to replace`NaN` with `-9` using the `max` function knowing that `max(NaN, -9) = -9`. What I have tried is :

```
from numpy import   NaN

l = [NaN, 5, -12, NaN, 9, 0]
ll = [-9, 5, -12, -9, 9, 0]

print([max(i) for i in zip(l, ll)])
# output : [nan, 5, -12, nan, 9, 0]
```

but the output is still the same list. Can't figure out how to code this.

Comment: "knowing that `max(NaN, -9) = -9`" _citation needed_. Perhaps they meant `max(-9, NaN)`?

Comment: @Brian I think you are right otherwise there's no way that I could do.

Comment: YOu can use `zip(ll,l)` for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nan_to_num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) function to change the NaN value to any number

```py
from numpy import NaN,nan_to_num

l = [NaN, 5, -12, NaN, 9, 0]
ll = [-9, 5, -12, -9, 9, 0]

print([max(nan_to_num(i,nan=-9)) for i in zip(l, ll)])
# is same as
# print([nan_to_num(i,nan=-9) for i in l])
# change nan=-9 to any number of your choice.
```

OUTPUT `[-9.0, 5, -12, -9.0, 9, 0]`

Here you got `-9.0` instead of `-9` (I think because NaN Type is float).

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's [`nanmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html#numpy-nanmax) function:

```
from numpy import NaN, nanmax

l = [NaN, 5, -12, NaN, 9, 0]
ll = [-9, 5, -12, -9, 9, 0]

print([nanmax(x) for x in zip(l, ll)])
```

Output:

```
[-9, 5, -12, -9, 9, 0]
```